# Java library options to efficiently transfer data between servers?

Tags: java, web-services

Scenario:

I have server A and B and data will constantly be transferred from A to B. The addresses of A and B are fixed and known so no naming service is required. The data is like an array list. Each piece will normally be of 10-20 Megabytes containing millions of elements while each element is relatively pretty small.

What Java libraries could be used to efficiently transfer data **except** JSON marshalling/unmarshalling or object serialization/deserialization (as these are known solutions to me)?

Comment: You can use XML format as you ruled out Json and serialized data. And, also you can set up socket connection btwn servers.

Comment: Use compression techniques such as [Snappy or GZIP](http://geekmantra.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/compression-in-kafka-gzip-or-snappy/) to reduce the size of data. Another suggestion shall be to look at fast RPC library such as Apache thrift or Google protobuff to implement the client & server.

Comment: @HussainPirosha nice to know these. looking into them.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just opening a ServerSocket on one, listen there for a Socket that's requesting a connection from the other, and then write the data as a byte stream?

If you want to be fancy you can create a simple protocol that adds some error checking to the data to be sent, like number of bytes and maybe a hash.